# populate list view with string array

Tags: android, android-listview

```
<products>
<product productName="Invega"/>                 
<product productName="Aciphex"/> 
<product productName="Doribax"/>
<product productName="Duragesic"/>
<product productName="Cetraxal"/>
<product productName="Caelyx"/>
<product productName="Axert"/>
<product productName="Aci-jel"/>
<product productName="Concerta"/>
<product productName="Elmiron"/>
</product>
```

Above is my XML file. I want to parse it with listview. My list view contains a checkbox. I want to populate the check box with the productnames. I tried many ways to do this, but I failed. Can anybody provide the code for this? Please help me.

Comment: "i want to populate the check box with the productnames" - Do you really mean 'checkbox'? A checkbox can only contain a check or not, it can't contain text.

Comment: Are you using android list activity or custom adapters?

Comment: and where is the XML file located?

Comment: BTW you are missing a s in the closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show text along with Check Box, then you should use CheckedTextView Control of android. As, Check Box alone doesn't support text.